# How to reshape array from (n,1) to (n, )?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, shapes

I have an array of arrays with n number of 'rows'. Iam aware that reshape ((n,1)) can turn an array into (n,1) but is there a way to do the opposite? I tried array[0] but that did not seem to work.

My current array structured as follows with shape (n,1):

```
[[array([1.00556293, 0.9377474 , 0.87450538, 0.81552842, 0.76052888])]
[array([1.00705293, 0.9217973 , 0.84375929, 0.77232786, 0.70694371])]
[array([1.00591583, 0.93394283, 0.86711948, 0.80507733, 0.74747427])]
...
[array([1.        , 0.92437698, 0.85447281, 0.78985499, 0.73012378])]
[array([1.        , 0.91608767, 0.83921662, 0.76879599, 0.70428453])]
[array([1.        , 0.92008808, 0.84656208, 0.77891168, 0.71666735])]]
```

Is it possible to reshape this into the following with shape (n,)?

```
[array([1.00556293, 0.9377474 , 0.87450538, 0.81552842, 0.76052888])
array([1.00705293, 0.9217973 , 0.84375929, 0.77232786, 0.70694371])
array([1.00591583, 0.93394283, 0.86711948, 0.80507733, 0.74747427])
...
array([1.        , 0.92437698, 0.85447281, 0.78985499, 0.73012378])
array([1.        , 0.91608767, 0.83921662, 0.76879599, 0.70428453])
array([1.        , 0.92008808, 0.84656208, 0.77891168, 0.71666735])]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have an array with shape (n ,1), you have a list of lists containing one array each. And apparently you want to get a list of arrays, not an array with shape (n, ). What was the problem with `array[0]`?

Comment: " Iam aware that reshape ((n,1)) can turn an array into (n,1) but is there a way to do the opposite?" What happened when you tried reading the documentation for `reshape`?

Comment: The input and output aren't syntactically valid cause they're missing commas. Is that intentional? By the way, if you're asking about NumPy, please add the [tag:numpy] tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 'array.flatten'

```py
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
flat_a = a.flatten()

print(flat_a )

#prints >>> [1,2,3,4]
```